# The bandwidth Ω of a low-pass signal f(t) ↔ F(ω)

Tags: frequency, energy, bandwidth, low-pass

I'm not sure about the answers to the two parts of this question:

> The bandwidth Ω of a low-pass signal f(t) ↔ F(ω) is defined by the constraint:
>
> $$ \frac{1}{2\pi } \int_{- \Omega }^{\Omega } \left | F(\omega ) \right |^{2} d\omega = 0.8W_{f} $$
>
> where Wf denotes the energy of signal f(t).
>
> (a) What fraction of the signal energy Wf is contained in the frequency band 0 < ω < Ω?
>
> (b) The signal f(t) is filtered using a linear system with a frequency response H(ω) satisfying H(ω) = 0 for |ω| < Ω and |H(ω)| = 1 for |ω| ≥ Ω. What is the total energy of the system output y(t) in terms of the energy Wf of the input f(t)?

Thanks

Comment: We tend to frown on homework questions unless you show a good effort to answer them yourself. What have you tried, and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @JoeHass For part a, I think that one half of the signal energy is contained in the frequency band since it is one half of the low pass signal. Would this be correct though? For b, I don't really know what kind of answer I'm aiming for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

(a) By [Parseval's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem) the energy of a signal can be computed in the time domain as well as in the frequency domain:

$$W_f=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f^2(t)dt=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|F(\omega)|^2d\omega\tag{1}$$

The energy in the frequency band \$\omega_1<\omega<\omega_2\$ is then given by

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\omega_1}^{\omega_2}|F(\omega)|^2d\omega$$

(b) The frequency response of the filtered output is

$$Y(\omega)=F(\omega)H(\omega)$$
and by (1) its energy is

$$W_y=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|Y(\omega)|^2d\omega=
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|F(\omega)|^2|H(\omega)|^2d\omega=\\
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{-\Omega}|F(\omega)|^2d\omega+
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\Omega}^{\infty}|F(\omega)|^2d\omega$$

Comment: Thank you. So, the energy of Y is the remaining energy from Wf and thus Wy=0.2Wf because it is the area outside of the -Ω to Ω band, right?

Comment: Yes, you got it!